# Importing TensorFlow "async" syntax error

Tags: tensorflow, syntax-error

I am trying to use the module imageai for a project and ran the line "from imageai.Detection import ObjectDetection". However, when I do so, this error appears:

```
File /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages/tensorflow/python/pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py:114
    def TFE_ContextOptionsSetAsync(arg1, async):
                                         ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

I found someone who had the same issue here: https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/20690 , but I'm not quite sure how to edit the last file of the trace where the error occurs. Does anyone have any tips on how to do this? Thanks!

I have tried looking at the above GitHub error but am not sure how to approach it.

Comment: You installed a version of tensorflow that does not support Python 3.10, how did you do that exactly?

Comment: I'm not sure? I downloaded tensorflow using "pip install tensorflow" in my terminal.

Comment: Which version of TensorFlow did you install then?

Comment: I installed tensorflow 2 from this website: https://www.tensorflow.org/install

Comment: TensorFlow 2 has many versions, you need to be specific, you are having people guess the problem.

Comment: My apologies, I am new to tensorflow. I'm not quite sure what version I downloaded. I simply ran "pip install tensorflow" in my terminal, nothing more.

Comment: pip show tensorflow would give you that information

Answer (score 0):

`ImageAI` uses `Pytorch` as backend. So you need to install all the required libraries before installing and importing the `imageai` module.

Please use the code below to install `imageai` in your system:

```
pip install cython pillow>=7.0.0 numpy>=1.18.1 opencv-python>=4.1.2 torch>=1.9.0 --extra-index-url https://download.pytorch.org/whl/cpu torchvision>=0.10.0 --extra-index-url https://download.pytorch.org/whl/cpu pytest==7.1.3 tqdm==4.64.1 scipy>=1.7.3 matplotlib>=3.4.3 mock==4.0.3

pip install imageai --upgrade
```

Now, import the Object detection from imageai:

```
from imageai.Detection import ObjectDetection
```

Please refer this [link](https://imageai.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) for more details.

**Note:** You can easily install `imageai` in Google Colab with this code

```
!pip install imageai
from imageai.Detection import ObjectDetection
```

**Hints:** Please use below code to install, import and check the `TensorFlow` version

```
pip install tensorflow
import tensorflow as tf
tf.__version__
```